# Specifying boundary points on GUI using c#

Tags: c#

I'm working on simulator, it has number of points. what i need is knowing how to specify the points which is the nearest one to any border of the four borders. I.e connect closed shape and ignore the points in the middle 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If the boundaries form a rectangle shape which is axis aligned (like a monitor screen, for example), then you can take the four points with maximum and minimum x and y values.

You can enumerate all of the points and find the points nearest the boundaries.

Pseudocode:

```
var minimumX = int.MaxValue
var maximumX = int.MinValue
var minimumY = int.Maxvalue
var maximumY = int.MinValue
foreach(var point in points)
{
    if (point.x < minimumX) minimumX = point.x;
    if (point.x > maximumX) maximumX = point.x;
    if (point.y < minimumY) minimumY = point.y;
    if (point.y > maximumY) maximumY = point.y;
}
```

You can now use minimum and maximum x and y to create a bounding rectangle that contains all points.

A slightly more performant method would track the minimum and maximum x and y as each point is added to the field. This way, there would be no need to enumerate all points.